# How to use an Azure database with a WCF service?

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, azure, ef-code-first

I created a WCF service that succesfully runs from Azure using the WCFServiceWebRole. Now I want the code of the WCF service to use a database that should be created using Entity Framework Code First. I created the entities and the context in a separate project. I am able to create and use the database from a local test project with the an app.config like this (pretty standard):

```html
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=MyLocalDb;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Integrated Security=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|MyLocalDbFile.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

But now I face the challenge to deploy the code to Azure. I added EntityFramework to the WCFServiceWebRole project using NuGet, but the web.config is not altered as the app.config usually is. I rented a database on Azure, I can connect to it using SQL Server Object Explorer. But there it ends.

When I look at the context menu for the WCF project I can choose between 'Publish to Microsoft Azure' (which works to deploy the WCF service, but does nothing else) and 'Publish...' The latter supposedly should give the option to deploy a database ([Example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/09/ef-code-first-migrations-deployment-to-an-azure-cloud-service.aspx)), but no database is found by the wizard.

Is there a noob guide for this? My google skills failed me...

Comment: Does this manual help? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/09/ef-code-first-migrations-deployment-to-an-azure-cloud-service.aspx

Comment: I already referenced that blog in my posting....

Comment: Isnt the wizard searching for sql server instances locally? Perhaps it works if you first create a database using the Azure portal, and in the wizard, you configure the details of the database that you created before.